# "DB21018E A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing"

Tags: db2

This is my first time using db2. this error shows up once i run the
`db2`
command on the admin db2 CLP.
I have tried searching up the problem, but none of the answers have worked for me.

Comment: You will need to improve your question before anyone can help you.  Please learn how to ask a good question. for example, what operating system are you using?  What Db2 product is installed?  What version is it? (`db2level`).  Which commands are you running to get this error?

Comment: Also, take the time to study the information about this error code, in the on-line Knowledge centre:    https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-db20000-db29999#db21018e

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, 
OS: Windows 10 Home.
Product: db2 community 11.5.
db2level produces "SQL1022C There is not enough memory available to process the command" error.
The command was just ```db2```.

Thanks a lot for the help. I already posted the solution for my case in the asnwers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that I installed db2 in my D: drive. once I deleted it and reinstalled it in my C: drive, it worked as expected.